# Problem with magento 2 price point and video

Tags: magento2

Have a problem with the magento price point.
When look price on store all its ok but when click on product first time show currect example 4 050Euro but after few second price show like a 40 50 euro.
On link can look problem.
Any have idea how to fix this ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DljzvQwOitA
Good day

Comment: "Video unavailable
This video has been removed by the uploader"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask